# GPS System wont restart after calling "removeUpdates"

Tags: android, gps, locationmanager, locationlistener

In my application I call "requestLocationUpdates" in onStart() method and I receive updates properly.

When I turn the GPS off by calling "removeUpdate(locationlistener)" I stop receiving updates as expected.

The problem is that when I want to restart the GPS system by calling "requestLocationUpdates" method again it isn't working! It never enters the "onLocationChanged" or "onStatusChanged" methods

my gpsLocationListener code;

```
public final LocationListener gpsLocationListener = new LocationListener() {
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        switch (status) {
        case LocationProvider.AVAILABLE:
            Logging.TraceMessage("GPS available again", Logging.INFORMATION, Logging.MAINACTIVITY);
            break;
        case LocationProvider.OUT_OF_SERVICE:
            Logging.TraceMessage("GPS out of service", Logging.INFORMATION, Logging.MAINACTIVITY);
            deviceSettings.gpsStatus = "2";
            break;
        case LocationProvider.TEMPORARILY_UNAVAILABLE:
            Logging.TraceMessage("GPS temporarily unavailable", Logging.INFORMATION, Logging.MAINACTIVITY);
            break;
        }
    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        Logging.TraceMessage("GPS Provider Enabled", Logging.INFORMATION, Logging.MAINACTIVITY);
    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        Logging.TraceMessage("GPS Provider Disabled", Logging.INFORMATION, Logging.MAINACTIVITY);
        deviceSettings.gpsStatus = "2";
    }

    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if(location == null) return;

        tempLoc.setItem(location.getLongitude(), location.getLatitude(), deviceSettings.getCurrentTime(), deviceSettings.satelliteCount, location.getSpeed());
            if (!SafeLocation.IsSafe(tempLoc) ){
            return;
        }

        deviceSettings.currX = tempLoc._x;
        deviceSettings.currY = tempLoc._y;
        deviceSettings.currSpeed = tempLoc._speed;
        deviceSettings.currValid = true;

    }
};
```

my removeupdates code;

```
if( ! deviceSettings.isprogramModeActive ){

                         if(gpsLocationListener != null){
                             try {
                                 locationManager.removeUpdates(gpsLocationListener);
                             } catch (Exception e) {
                             }                           
                         }
                         mylocatewait(30000);//30 saniye bekle
                         continue;
                    }
```

my request again code:

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, ServerSettings.getGpsPer()*1000, 0, gpsLocationListener);
```

Comment: i know you're turkish, but the grammar of your question makes it difficult to understand your desired program flow.

Comment: sorry i edited it, can you please tell me if you are not understand it already.

Comment: are you emulating or running on a device? are you sending locations through DMMS?

Comment: NO i am working on a device. "requestLocationUpdates" code doesnt work after call the "removeUpdates".

Comment: I have never had any trouble restarting the GPS system, which makes me wonder if your "stop" logic is being called after you restart the system. Either that or your "ServerSettings.getGpsPer()" call is returning a very large number.  I think you will need to provide more code or some better log outputs

Comment: my application has got two mode, active mode and passive mode. I have got a thread and i am controlling mode. if(mode == passive){gps = off} else if(mode == active){gps = on}   This is my application work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve the problem!

I crate an call a handler from thread.

```
locateHandler.sendEmptyMessage(1);
```

I call the following code from a handler, not in the thread.

```
 Handler locateHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            super.handleMessage(msg);
            if(msg.what == 0)
                locationManager.removeUpdates(gpsLocationListener);
            else if(msg.what == 1)
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, ServerSettings.getGpsPer()*1000, 0, gpsLocationListener);
        }
    };
```

Comment: handler.post is probably a tad cleaner, though

Comment: i will accept it, 7 hours later(stackoverflow quality standarts)

Comment: Had the same problem.  A little simpler approach that worked is:

gpsHandler.post(new Runnable() {public void run() {locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 25, locationListener);}});

and then to remove 

gpsHandler.post(new Runnable() {public void run() {locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);}});